# How to prevent multiple instances of an application in recent app screen while using multiple tasks?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Android application having 2 `activities` other than `MainActivity`, both `activities` are having `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. I navigated to each activity and then i open recent screens it'll show **3 instances** of my application, one for application and each one for both activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need to create separate tasks (which I doubt, this is a very rare case), then you need to do the following:

- If you want each task to show up in the list of recent tasks, then you will need a way for the user to differentiate. To do this you should provide a different icon for each `<activity>` (using `android:icon=""`) and/or a different label for each `<activity>` (using `android:label=""`).
- If you only want one task to show up in the list of recent tasks, then you need to set the following on the other `<activity>` tags in the manifest:

  `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the manifest file in your launcher activity `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

```
 <activity
   android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">        
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />       
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: my requirement is to create separate task for each Activity.  For launchMode="singleTop" is working fine but for launchMode="singleInstance" it's showing multiple instances of application.

Comment: Why you need launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: i want to run each activity in separate task, when user enters the activity for the first time i want to instantiate activity and every other time i just navigate to existing activity from  separate task, so by doing this i'm just navigating to existing activity and no need to create new instance of activity for every time user enters the activity

Comment: If you run each activity in seperate task, then each activiy should seen as multiple instances.

Comment: No. If we use launchMode="singleInstance", only one instance of activity is create in separate task for the first time. So from then every time you call that activity, android won't create new instance of activity, but existing activity will be focused.

Comment: If you are creating an instance for 3 activities in separate tasks, then you will have 3 separate instance for your application.Each has launching activity will be that specific activity.

Comment: Yes, that is what my question is. I just want to know is there any way to prevent multiple instances of an application in recent app screen while using multiple tasks

Comment: @Yatish what was the solution?